# Size of memory aligned struct

Tags: gcc, struct, memory-alignment

```
struct Test
{
    int a;
    char b;
    int c;
} __attribute__((packed, aligned( 128 )))test;
```

sizeof( test ) returns 128 .

Why is the size not 9 ?

Is it that memory is rounded of to multiple of 128 ?

For example:

```
struct Test
{
 int b;
 char c;
} test;
```

sizeof( test ) returns 8 ( rounded of to multiple of 8 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to create an array of `struct Test` then each element would need to be 128 byte aligned, therefore each instance of the struct needs to be padded to a multiple of 128 bytes to maintain this. Hence `sizeof(struct Test)` = 128.

Comment: Isn't it that only the starting address needs to be memory aligned ?

Comment: Nope - every instance of the struct needs to have the same alignment.